# Disable Quickhelp in Xcode 3.2

Tags: xcode

Since upgrading to Xcode 3.2, I miss the old style *option + double click* on a word to bring up the documentation within Xcode.

Now, I get the new 'quickhelp' menu, which isn't all that helpful, and just means that I need to click one more time to get to the documentation!

Is there an easy way to return Xcode back to its old ways? (I'm probably missing something in preferences!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holding Cmd + Option and double-clicking will take you directly to the definition of the symbol you clicked on in the docs. So you don't need to rewire the app if you can rewire your brain to just hold down one more key!